# GET request is Sent Twice; Once With the Query String Inside the URL and Once Without It

Tags: javascript, python, flask

My issue is that whenever the button `const loadOldPlayer` is clicked, it sends two GET requests, as shown in the screenshot below. What this results in is the wrong template being rendered (`showsPlayer.html` should be what is rendered but instead it just renders `playerView.html`). I can't figure out why this is happening, so any help is appreciated. Below the screenshot is my code.
[image: screenshot of issue]

```
let playerName
const loadOldPlayer = document.getElementById('playerLoader');

const enterProfile = (usedToLoad) => {
    console.log(playerName)
    if (usedToLoad) {
        playerName = document.getElementById('loadPlayerName').value
    };
    const playerData = {
        playerName: playerName
    };
    const JSONdata = JSON.stringify(playerData);
    fetch(`/profile?tags=${JSONdata}`, { method: "GET" }).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            document.getElementById('loaderLabel').innerHTML = "Loading Player"
        }
        else {
            alert("Something bad happened.");
        };
    });
};

loadOldPlayer.addEventListener("click", enterProfile.bind(true));
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from static.SNEKfiles import SpaceShipGame
import json


game_app = Flask(__name__)

@game_app.route('/') 
@game_app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("HTMLPage1.html")

@game_app.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        playerName = request.args.get('tags')
        if playerName != None:
            print("got the name")
            return render_template("showsPlayer.html")
        else:
            print("here is issue")
            return render_template("playerView.html")

if __name__== "__main__":
    game_app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=7777)
```

Yes my HTML files are badly named, I'll probably get around to fixing that. Eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm inexperienced with this, so I might be completely wrong here. Anyway, try adding the event listener with

```
loadOldPlayer.addEventListener("click", function() {
    enterProfile(true);
});
```

instead of

```
loadOldPlayer.addEventListener("click", enterProfile.bind(true));
```

I think the bind(true) might be causing the empty querystring.
If this doesn't work, could you add some debug output?

Also, the `return render_template("showsPlayer.html")` successfully returns the html, but the client never actually uses it. Try using

```
fetch(`/profile?tags=${JSONdata}`, { method: "GET" }).then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
        document.getElementById('loaderLabel').innerHTML = "Loading Player"
        return response.text()
    }
    else {
        alert("Something bad happened.");
    }
}).then((html) => {
    console.log(html) // should show response html
    document.open();
    document.write(html); // writes response html to body
    document.close();
})
```

Document.write() is considered bad practice, but it is the only way (that I know of, at least) to dynamically replace the entire page.

Comment: This definitely helped, but it still won't render ```showsPlayer.html```. I might be able to open it on the js side though, as a .then statement.

Comment: nvm about doing it on the js side.

Comment: I didn't realize that the client didn't use the response html, I edited the post.

Comment: console briefly flashes "undefined" before clearing.

Comment: can you post all of the code? It works on my machine.

Comment: could me passing a variable in with the rendered template cause this error?

Comment: I've entirely given up on this, as there are a few different ways I could accomplish the same thing with less strife. I'm going to accept this despite it not being finished because of your insane patience with my inherent stupidity. Thanks for all your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

I edited this answer because I didn't notice your use of the .bind(true) earlier.

The event listener expects a function reference, which is what Quackers had you implement. Similar to Quackers solution, but using the shorter arrow function form :

```js
loadOldPlayer.addEventListener("click", () => enterProfile(true));
```

That way, you are passing a function reference, and that function, when called by the event, just call your function with the value set to "true" as you expect.

Your original code was using .bind() which creates a new function with `this` set to the value you provided to `.bind`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind.

By passing `enterProfile.bind(true)` to `addEventListener`, you ended up passing a new `enterProfile` function to handle the click event (that new function having the `this` set to `true`, which had no effect for you).

When the event fired, the browser actually was passing the Event object to the function, not the value `true` (see event callbacks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback).

At that point, the `if (usedToLoad)` was entirely dependant on what Event data was passed and if that evaluated to a truthy value or not.